# Html canvas free transform

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to transform a non-uniformed portion of image in a canvas element to a proper rectangle (ie. Like taking a non-rectangle portion of an image in photoshop and using Distort to make it rectangle), but am having difficulty understanding Canvas Matrix Transforms.

I am not after code, just a point in the right direction, in terms of understanding how I could achieve this.

Cheers

Update 1: Incase I didn't explain well enough https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGZX5.png

Update 2: The those boxes are an area inside a photo which was added to the canvas, essentially I am cropping and straightening a portion of the image.

Comment: Don't use the Matrix for this, just move the corners to any coordinates you want.

Answer (score 0):

In html5 canvas you can apply only [affine transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) using `transform` or `setTransform()` methods, so you need to know what is the matrix applied already and using the inverse matrix to make it look like a square area, for other transformations (non-affine), it is needed some math knowledge (that I don't have), create or search for an implementation for Canvas API (which works only with affine transformations).